# Can't connect to iperf3 running in Azure Container Instances

Tags: iperf3, azure-container-instances

trying a quick experiment with ACI to see if I can use it to host iperf3 for some on demand network performance testing. The docker image is https://hub.docker.com/r/netgio/iperf3server/

I can get the container up and running but when I try to connect to it the iperf client gives me the error "iperf3: error - control socket has closed unexpectedly"

I was hoping this would be a simple, single port, single instance use case. are there any specifics related to socket connectivity into ACI instances that would affect this?

EDIT: 
iPerf3 defaults to TCP port 5201 so to ensure ACI port mappings are working as expected I created an nginx docker image configured to listen on port 5201 and deployed to ACI.  This worked as expected (I could access the default home page at http://:5201).  So the issue seems to be specific to whatever iPerf3 is doing with its sockets.

Note the error happens almost immediately at launch of the client iperf3 process.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is experiencing an outage right now. You're probably being impacted.
http://downdetector.com/status/windows-azure

Comment: Deploying a basic nginx instance on port 80 is working fine, and the issue persists.  Ironically this image "works on my machine" and on an Azure VM.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Multiple Azure regions were taken down during the time of your question by a misconfiguration at Level 3. If you're still having problems, it's probably not due to the outage.